# Concatenate on JobID

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate a selected column in a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808613/concatenate-a-selected-column-in-a-single-query)

I know this is fairly simple in MySQL, but i don't know how to do it in SQLServer. I have a table containing two columns. UserID & TagID. I'd like to concatenate TagID into a comma separated string, where the result is grouped by UserID. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would ythink something lik ethis might be what you are looking for :

```
SELECT ''+Table1.UserID+','+Table2.TagID+'' AS CombinedCSVColumn
      , SUM(Table1.Value) AS Value
From dbo.Table1 as Table1
INNER JOIN db.Table2 as Table2
ON Table1.EmployeeID = Table2.EmployeeID
GROUP BY ''+Table1.UserID+','+Table2.TagID+''
```

That is if they come from two Tables. For one table is similar.

Regards

Mac

Comment: This is only possible when i know exactly how many items to concatinate, but it's dynamic and per User how many they are.

Comment: Did my code help you? If not - let me have more info and I will see what I can do for you, otherwise, award it as having answered the question you first asked. Cheers, Mac